# How to read the Vim "keybinding" (keyboard shortcut?), "<C-f>"? How to read other Vim documentation?

Tags: vim

How does one read the following Vim keybindings:

`<C-f>`
`ZZ`
`dd`
`:wq`

How to read other Vim documentation?

Answer (score 6):

Stuff with < C-letter> is control+letter.

ZZ is just two capital Z's; dd two lowercase d's.

:wq is a colon followed by (you guessed it) w and q.

Type :help or press F1 in vim to find your documentation, or look at [vim documentation online](http://www.vim.org/docs.php).

Your best bet would be to dive head first into vim and disable your arrow keys.  Check out implementing a .vimrc... you can have a lot of with this.  Sometimes metaprogramming is more fun than programming itself!

Comment: +1 for "sometimes metaprogramming is more fun than programming itself".